# In c programming, I can not enter more than 78 input. After that I/O does not work. Is there any way to enter more input?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>

int isPerfect(int n){
    double i=2;
    float value=0;
    int just=0,f=0,x=0;
    f=log(n)/log(2);
    for (i=2; i<=f; ++i){
        value=pow(n,(1/i));
        just=value;
        if(value==just && pow(just, i)==n){
            x=1;
            break;
        }else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
int main(){
    printf("Range:");
    int l=0,h=0,j=0,i=0;
    while(1){
        scanf("%d %d",&l,&h);
        if(l<0 || h<0 || (h-l)<0 || h<l){
            printf("Error");
            return -1;
            break;
        }
        int count=0;
        for(i=l;i<=h;i++){
            j=isPerfect(i);
            if(i!=1 && j!=1){
                count+=1;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was working on a program to find all the perfect power in a range(for example, 1 100000000). This is the function of my program to find perfect power. I used while(1){..} for input in the main function. But after working with 78 input ranges, the program's I/O does not work. I have tried dynamic allocation but still it cannot process more than 78 input ranges. I am getting this message "Time limit exceeded #stdin #stdout 5s 4336KB" in ideone.com. Is there any other way to make a program accept more input? or any other more efficient algorithm to process more than 300 input ranges.

Output:
(78th output)494986
(79th input)1 10000001
(no output)

Comment: Your posted code don't have any statement to do I/O. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: no worries. @pmg

Comment: It would be sieve algorithm for perfect power testing but I'm new in stack overflow. So they didn't allow me to create a tag. @WeatherVane

Comment: `pow(n,(1/i))` is calculating the `i`th root but `pow()` (and floating point arithmetic generally) isn't very accurate if you are hoping for an integer result.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. that is why I put the result in float value.then comparing it with integer just. Actually, I cannot overcome the barrier "Time limit exceeded". @WeatherVane

Comment: Perhaps it exceeds the time limit due to failure to find an integer result. Suppose `pow` returns `48.999999` if the true root is `49` then converting to `int` and comparing `48` with `48.999999` isn't going to equate.

Comment: It works. The answer is 99989509. It took 30-40 seconds on my system to solve. As a result, you need a system that should run the code at least 1 minute before fail.

Comment: Actually, stdin is 1 to 1000000 , 1 to 100, 887 to 1000 like 300 ranges. I have to calculate all the ranges within 5second. After 78th input the I/O acts like broken. @LORDTEK

Comment: Work the other way round: Instead of testing all numbers in the range, generate all 25 powers of 2, then all 15 powers of 3, then all 12 powers of 4 and so on in the range. The number of powers you generate decrease rapidly and you don't need to generate powers for numbers greater than the square root of the upper limit at all. Be aware that you will generate doubles, so you will need a mathod to throw these out.

Comment: Thank you. I will be careful about that. but I am not sure that is affecting the output. I am using Xcode and VSCode. I also tried in linux. it is showing correct output. @WeatherVane

Comment: Using `float` instead of `double` or even `long double` is probably misguided.

Comment: Could possibly be that the numbers are just too big for `int`

Comment: Thank you very much. The program is now working. @MOehm